# How to mock Entity Framework's FromSqlRaw method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, xunit, nsubstitute

I am writing a Unit Test and need to mock Entity Framework's .FromSqlRaw method. When the method is executed in the class under test, it throws following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is no method
> 'FromSqlOnQueryable' on type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions' that
> matches the specified arguments.

Following is class under test:

```
public class PowerConsumptionRepository : IPowerConsumptionRepository
    {
        private readonly IDatabaseContext _databaseContext;
        private readonly IDateTimeHelper _dateTimeHelper;

        public PowerConsumptionRepository(IDatabaseContext databaseContext, IDateTimeHelper dateTimeHelper)
        {
            _databaseContext = databaseContext;
            _dateTimeHelper = dateTimeHelper;
        }
        public List<IntervalCategoryConsumptionModel> GetCurrentPowerConsumption(string siteId)
        {
            var currentDate = _dateTimeHelper
                .ConvertUtcToLocalDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow, ApplicationConstants.LocalTimeZone)
                .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            var currentDateParameter = new SqlParameter("currentDate", currentDate);
            var measurements = _databaseContext.IntervalPowerConsumptions
                .FromSqlRaw(SqlQuery.CurrentIntervalPowerConsumption, currentDateParameter)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToList();
            return measurements;
        }
    }
```

Unit Test:

```
    public class PowerConsumptionRepositoryTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void TestTest()
        {
            var data = new List<IntervalCategoryConsumptionModel>
            {
                new IntervalCategoryConsumptionModel
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Hvac = 10                    
                },
                new IntervalCategoryConsumptionModel
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Hvac = 10
                }
            }.AsQueryable();
            var dateTimeHelper = Substitute.For<IDateTimeHelper>();
            dateTimeHelper.ConvertUtcToLocalDateTime(Arg.Any<DateTime>(), Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(DateTime.Now);
            var mockSet = Substitute.For<DbSet<IntervalCategoryConsumptionModel>, IQueryable<IntervalCategoryConsumptionModel>>();
            ((IQueryable<IntervalCategoryConsumptionModel>)mockSet).Provider.Returns(data.Provider);
            ((IQueryable<IntervalCategoryConsumptionModel>)mockSet).Expression.Returns(data.Expression);
            ((IQueryable<IntervalCategoryConsumptionModel>)mockSet).ElementType.Returns(data.ElementType);
            ((IQueryable<IntervalCategoryConsumptionModel>)mockSet).GetEnumerator().Returns(data.GetEnumerator());
            var context = Substitute.For<IDatabaseContext>();
            context.IntervalPowerConsumptions = (mockSet);
            var repo = new PowerConsumptionRepository(context, dateTimeHelper);
            var result = repo.GetCurrentPowerConsumption(Arg.Any<string>());
            result.Should().NotBeNull();
        }
    }
```

Comment: To [quote the EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/#unit-testing): _we never try to mock DbContext or IQueryable. Doing so is difficult, cumbersome, and fragile. **Don't do it.**_ (Their emphasis.)

Comment: Right. I understand. But does that mean I cannot unit test it?  I cannot use In-memory database as `.FromSqlRaw` executes SQL query.

Comment: Isn't that the problem then? That you are testing a class that is highly coupled with your database and now you want to abstract that database but finding it very hard or impossible? To properly test `PowerConsumptionRepository` you should probably use a "real" database. I recently came across the post [Avoid In-Memory Databases for Tests](https://jimmybogard.com/avoid-in-memory-databases-for-tests/) by Jimmy Bogard which might give you some more perspective on this issue.

Comment: Or check for the provider type in your production code.

Answer (score 11):

In my scenario I use `FromSqlRaw` method for invoke stored procedure in my database.
For EntityFramework Core (version 3.1 works well for sure) I do it in this way:

Add virtual method to your `DbContext` class:

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> RunSql<TEntity>(string sql, params object[] parameters) where TEntity : class
{
    return this.Set<TEntity>().FromSqlRaw(sql, parameters);
}
```

It's just a simple **virtaul** wraper from static `FromSqlRaw`, so you can easily mock it:

```
var dbMock = new Mock<YourContext>();
var tableContent = new List<YourTable>()
{
    new YourTable() { Id = 1, Name = "Foo" },
    new YourTable() { Id = 2, Name = "Bar" },
}.AsAsyncQueryable();
dbMock.Setup(_ => _.RunSql<YourTable>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns(tableContent );
```

Call our new `RunSql` method instead of `FromSqlRaw`:

```
// Before
//var resut = dbContext.FromSqlRaw<YourTable>("SELECT * FROM public.stored_procedure({0}, {1})", 4, 5).ToListAsync();
// New
var result = dbContext.RunSql<YourTable>("SELECT * FROM public.stored_procedure({0}, {1})", 4, 5).ToListAsync();
```

Last, but not least, you need to add `AsAsyncQueryable()` extension method to your test project. It's provided by user @vladimir in a brilliant answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58204157/1385292):

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> AsAsyncQueryable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
    {
        return new NotInDbSet<T>( input );
    }

}

public class NotInDbSet< T > : IQueryable<T>, IAsyncEnumerable< T >, IEnumerable< T >, IEnumerable
{
    private readonly List< T > _innerCollection;
    public NotInDbSet( IEnumerable< T > innerCollection )
    {
        _innerCollection = innerCollection.ToList();
    }

    public IAsyncEnumerator< T > GetAsyncEnumerator( CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken() )
    {
        return new AsyncEnumerator( GetEnumerator() );
    }

    public IEnumerator< T > GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _innerCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public class AsyncEnumerator : IAsyncEnumerator< T >
    {
        private readonly IEnumerator< T > _enumerator;
        public AsyncEnumerator( IEnumerator< T > enumerator )
        {
            _enumerator = enumerator;
        }

        public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            return new ValueTask();
        }

        public ValueTask< bool > MoveNextAsync()
        {
            return new ValueTask< bool >( _enumerator.MoveNext() );
        }

        public T Current => _enumerator.Current;
    }

    public Type ElementType => typeof( T );
    public Expression Expression => Expression.Empty();
    public IQueryProvider Provider => new EnumerableQuery<T>( Expression );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The in-memory provider can't do it as it's a relational operation. Ignoring the philosophical side of it there are probably a couple of ways you could solve it.

1. Mocking the query provider

Under the covers it's runs through the `IQueryProvider.CreateQuery<T>(Expression expression)` method so you can use a mocking framework to intercept the invocation and return what you want. That's how [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing) (disclaimer I am the author) [does it](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing#fromsql). This is how I unit test `FromSql*` invocations in my code.

2. A better in-memory provider

I haven't used it much but my understanding is a provider like SQLite *may* support it.

To address the OP comments, WRT whether you should be using an in-memory provider/mocking the `DbContext`, we are in the realm of personal opinion. Mine is that I have no reservations using the in-memory provider, it's easy to use, reasonably fast and works well for many. I do agree that you shouldn't mock the `DbContext`, simply because it'd be really hard to do. [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing) doesn't mock the `DbContext` per se, it wraps over an in-memory provider and uses popular mocking frameworks to provide support for things like `FromSql*` and `ExecuteSql*`.

I read the linked article by Jimmy Bogard (who I have the utmost respect for), however on this topic I don't agree on all points. On the rare occasion that I have raw SQL in my data access layer, it's generally to invoke a stored procedure or function which already has been tested/has tests outside of my SUT. I generally treat them as a dependency; I should be able to write my unit tests for my SUT with that dependency returning the values required to adequately test my SUT.

Comment: I've tried your solution but all what can I get is exception: _'Constructor on type 'MyProject.Models.TestDbContext'_ not found.', what is wrong because my `TestDbContext` has a public parameterless constructor (`public TestDbContext() { }`).

Comment: If you're experiencing a problem with my library, pop an issue up on the repo with a working sample and I can help you further.

Answer (score 4):

With `.FromSqlRaw` you are sending raw sql query to the database engine.
If you really want to test that your application (`.FromsqlRaw`) works as expected, test it against an actual database.

Yes it is slower, yes it requires running database with some test data - and yes it will provide you strong confidence that your application is working.

All other tests (mocked or in-memory or sqlite) will provide you false feeling of confidence.